# Create a popup similar to WhatsApp popup notification in android studio

Tags: android-studio, push-notification, android-notifications, whatsapp

[WhatsApp popup notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdNbH.jpg)

Here is an image of what I am trying to implement. I couldn't find an answer on the internet. This is a Whatsapp popup notification (by default this option is turned off on WhatsApp).

Is this a notification, a dialogue box, or both? How do I implement this?